# Add abline to filled contour plot

Tags: r, graphics

I drew a contour plot and added a diagonal line:

```
library(MASS)
library(fields)
x <- c(21.06, 28.89, 23.00, 23.61, 23.61, 22.83, 30.44)
y <- c(26.56, 24.00, 13.06, 18.61, 18.61, 14.17, 25.33)
z <- kde2d(x, y, n=32, lims = c(0,32,0,32))
contour(z, col = "red", main = "Density estimation: contour plot",
       las=0,

    plot.title=
               {
      title(xlab=expression(alpha),cex.lab=2)
      mtext(expression(beta),2,cex=2,line=3,las=1)
               } 
)
abline(0, 1, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image: first graph]

I think I like the filled contour more, but now the line is off:

```
filled.contour(z,  plot.title={
   title(main = "Density estimation: contour plot")
   title(xlab=expression(alpha),cex.lab=2)
   mtext(expression(beta),2,cex=2,line=3,las=1)
 })
 abline(0, 1, col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

[image: second graph]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could throw the `abline` in there:

```
library(MASS)

x <- c(21.06, 28.89, 23.00, 23.61, 23.61, 22.83, 30.44)
y <- c(26.56, 24.00, 13.06, 18.61, 18.61, 14.17, 25.33)
z <- kde2d(x, y, n = 32, lims = c(0, 32, 0, 32))

filled.contour(z,  plot.title={
  title(main = "Density estimation: contour plot")
  title(xlab=expression(alpha),cex.lab=2)
  mtext(expression(beta),2,cex=2,line=3,las=1)
  abline(0, 1, col = "red", lwd = 2)
})
```

[image]

Or (as was suggested in a comment), you might be better off doing something like:

```
filled.contour(
  z,
  plot.title = {
    title(main = "Density estimation: contour plot")
    title(xlab = expression(alpha), cex.lab = 2)
    mtext(expression(beta), 2, cex = 2, line = 3, las = 1)
  },
  plot.axes = {
    abline(0, 1, col = "red", lwd = 2)
  }
)
```

Simply because it feels a little weird putting an `abline` in `plot.title`.

Comment: For some reason passing in the result from `lm` does not get displayed. Supplying the slope and intercept is not providing lines in accordance to the contour domain values, as if the outer contour domain is irrelevant to the context of the plot axes of this abline